# broken cron job after editing it

Tags: cron

I'm having some difficulties on understanding why the following cronjob does not work anymore:

```
30 3 * * * /path/to/backup_script.sh && tar -czvf /path/to/archived/backups/retain_last_3_backups/backup-community_$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S').tar.gz -C /path/to/source/backup/folder/ .
```

If I run it manually using the same user who own the crontab, it does work. It stopped to work when I edited it a couple of days ago adding `&& tar -czvf [...]`

should I call in a different way the `date` command? or escape the `$` (I'm going to test this now, just noticed it)?

Thanks to David Sánchez Martín, I found the specific log, it report the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` symbols are special in a `crontab` entry, so you can't use them directly in your `date` format string.

`man 5 crontab` writes

> The sixth field (the rest of the line) specifies  the  command  to  be  run.   The       entire  command  portion of the line, up to a newline or `%` character, will be executed       by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the `SHELL` variable of the cronfile.   Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to the command  as  standard input.

Answer (score 2):

First, to debug and monitorize this, as a rule of thumb, add a MAILTO variable in the crontab, should a problem arises in the standard error, it emails you.

```
# crontab -e
MAILTO=mymail@mydomain.com
30 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/blahblah.sh
```

Also notice if the command outputs something in the standard output you can redirect it to null if you don't want that in your mail .

```
30 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/blahblah.sh > /dev/null
```

Then, probably if you are unsure of the command make the date thing a variable, like this

```
30 3 * * * /path/to/backup_script.sh && THEDATE=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S) tar -czvf /path/to/archived/backups/retain_last_3_backups/backup-community_$THEDATE).tar.gz -C /path/to/source/backup/folder/ .
```

I think is more readable and you don't have a variable lurking around.

Comment: nice hints, but I don't think they are closely related in solving my issue

Comment: This hints are only for helping you now and in the future, with different crontabs. Also, this **should led you** to look at the email of the user that executes the crontab, THERE should be a log with the errors (look at `/var/spool/mail/theuser` , or something like this).

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, you was right I found the log of this crontab in `/var/spool/mail/theuser` , it was already logging. I'll update the question with the related error